# JPA not updating SQL-database properly

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I'm new to using JPA, and i have a person Entity class, where i want to display some information, at first when i made the class, i had the ID set to

```
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
```

which genereated an ID of 51, where i was told by my teacher to change it to:

```
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
```

so it would just start with 1 and then add up for each person.

Now i have a structure java class, where i want to delete the current database for each new instance i run the class, and i have this code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 


{
    HashMap<String, Object> puProperties = new HashMap<>();

    puProperties.put("javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source", "Scripts/ClearDB.sql");
    Persistence.generateSchema("jpadb", puProperties);


    puProperties.remove("javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source");
    Persistence.generateSchema("jpadb", puProperties);
}
```

with a script as such:

```
drop database jpadb if exists;
create database jpadb;
```

here is the error i get:

```
Internal Exception: 
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an 
error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if exists' at line 1
Error Code: 1064
Call: drop database jpadb if exists;
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="drop database jpadb if exists;")
[EL Warning]: 2018-09-11 16:14:41.361--ServerSession(2045766957)-- 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 
2.7.3.v20180807-4be1041): 
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Can't create database      
'jpadb'; database exists
Error Code: 1007
```

I don't know what the syntax error refers to?

Comment: According to the [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/drop-database.html) the syntax should be: `DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS jpadb`, with the name of the database at the end. Not `IF EXISTS` after the database name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your drop statement to

```
drop database if exists jpadb;
```

The error message is clear where your statement is wrong,

```
Call: drop database jpadb if exists;
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="drop database jpadb if exists;")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this script  ;

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS jpadb;
```

you have a snytax error with written which is `drop database jpadb if exists;` . Your problem is about sequence of keyword actually.
To see more [mysql Drop docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/drop-database.html)